# Android - prevent to open previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, fragmentmanager

guys.
This must be a silly question but i'm not managing to work this out. My scenario is: i have in my `MainActivity` a `BottomNavigation` which i navigate over three fragments. And my problem is that when the back button (from android bottom navigation toolbar) is pressed the previous fragment opens but i want the app to close. So my question is: how i manage to prevent the previous fragments to open?

PS: I know it has something to do with FragmentMananger back stack but i did not understand how to use it.

PS2: Sorry for bad english.

Comment: You shouldn't add the `replace` to backstack with `addToBackStack`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragments are on the backstack.

**Edit:**

Work with FragmentTransaction and use addToBackStack (null)

```
//  Create new fragment and transaction
    Fragment newFragment = new  ExampleFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onBackPressed()` method in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish(); //This would close the app
}
```

Word of caution. This would close the activity in all the cases when the user presses back. To avoid this perhaps you would like to create something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(someCondition) {
        finish(); //This would close the activity
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed(); //Fallbacks to default Android implementation
    }
}
```